# Datatype of a variable

Tags: javascript

I tried to search on internet to find the datatype of this variable but I couldn't find it.

I have a variable initialized like this:

```js
var pieData = [
    {
            value: 500,
            color:"#F38630"
    },
    {
            value : 10,
            color : "#E0E4CC"
    },
    {
            value : 200,
            color : "#69D2E7"
    }
];
```

I don't know what its datatype and how can I add more data in it.

Comment: `pieData` is an `array`.  It's elements are all `objects`.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have datatypes. It just has objects, arrays, numbers, strings like you are using them here. What are you looking for, why do you need to know a "datatype"? What data do you want to add?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript#JavaScript_and_Java "JavaScript's typing is dynamic (meaning a variable can hold an object of any type and cannot be restricted)"

Comment: dynamic typing doesn't equal "no typing". Even if variables are dynamically-typed, they've type while references to some object or primitive.

Comment: @bergi: what about null, regexp, boolean, uint8, typed arrays, views, etc?

Comment: @dandavis: Of course JavaScript has primitive types (which I didn't list all), and objects (with different constructors/prototypes and maybe even [[Class]] values), but it has no type system with any notion of abstract data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an array of objects.

- `[]` is a literal array. For example `["a", "b", "c"]`
- `{}` defines an object/associative array (i.e. the index can be of any type)

You can add more items to an array by using the `Array.push()` function:

```
var someArray = [{ value: 10, color: "#69D2E7" }];
someArray.push({ value: 389, color: "#FF0000" });
```

About the *data type*, well, let's call *the type* and it's `Array`.

You can always check the type by using the `typeof` operator:

```
console.log(typeof []) // ...outputs "object"
console.log(typeof "hello") // ...outputs "string"
```

Comment: An addendum: Parts of an object can be retrieved like so. `var value = valCol.value; valCol.value = 17;` Or: `var keyName = "value"; var value = valCol[keyName];`

Comment: for more about typeof/instanceof, see http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2013/07/javascript-datatypes.html

Answer (score 3):

That is an `Array` literal containing multiple `Object` literals, which have properties set to `String` literals.

That structure is what inspired the [JSON data-interchange format](http://json.org/).

`[]` is an array literal, the contents of which are comma separated. `[]` is empty. `['foo']` contains one string of `'foo'`. `['foo', 'bar']` contains `'foo'` and `'bar'`.

`{}` is an object literal, the contents of which are key-value pairs. `{}` is empty. `{foo: 'bar'}` contains a key of `'foo'` which has a value of `'bar'`. `{foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz'}` contains a key of `'foo'` with a value of `'bar'` and a key of `'fizz'` with a value of `'buzz'`.

To add more data to your original array (normalized form repeated for reference), simply add another object at the end of the array:

<sub>original</sub>

```
var pieData = [{
    value: 500,
    color: "#F38630"
}, {
    value: 10,
    color: "#E0E4CC"
}, {
    value: 200,
    color: "#69D2E7"
}];
```

<sub>additional object</sub>

```
var pieData = [{
    value: 500,
    color: "#F38630"
}, {
    value: 10,
    color: "#E0E4CC"
}, {
    value: 200,
    color: "#69D2E7"
}, { //new object starts here
    value: 80,
    color: "#123456"
}];
```

If you need to dynamically add more objects to `pieData`, you can use [standard array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods) such as `push`, `unshift`, and `splice`.